# "use" vs. "usage" in "The use(usage) of a different drug calls for a detailed justification"

Tags: word-choice

> The **use** of a different reference drug calls for a detailed scientific justification, as well as additional documents and data.

Would the word **usage** look okay in the place of this **use**?

> The **usage** of a different reference drug calls for a detailed scientific justification, as well as additional documents and data.

Judging [by this discussion on ELU SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34712/use-vs-usage), **use** might be more appropriate, but an English enthusiast friend [told me](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34848687#34848687) that he thinks **usage** might be okay too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Usage" might be ok, but it sounds clunky in that sentence.  The ELU article is pretty clear that "usage" describes a set of how something might be *used*.  In this context it's one use of one drug (as a reference) so I don't see how it's justified.

Anyway, I'm always a fan of clear, concise writing, so "use" (or a different, more targeted verb like "introduction") is far better.